# Erro para recuperar um Future List<Class> Dart

Tags: lista, dart, flutter

Pessoal esto tendo problema para recuperar os dados de uma função futura quando chega no snapshot... apresenta esse erro:

```
AsyncSnapshot<List<Episodio>>(ConnectionState.done, null, Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List.....

Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<class>>'
Onde posso está errando?
```

meu future funcao que vai ser passada mais a frente no `FutureBuilder`.

```
   Future <List<Episodio>> getAnime()async{
    try{
    List teste=[];
    List test=
    (widget.animes.temporada.map((t)=>t.episodios.map((e)=>Episodio(

       ))).toList()) ;

   return test;
 }catch(e){
    throw Exception(e);

  }
}
```

.. no Future Builder

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getAnime(),
          builder: (context,snapshot){
          if(!snapshot.hasData){return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);}
          else if(snapshot.hasError){return Center(child: Text("Erro"),);}
          else{
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){

                print (" teste:${snapshot.data[index]}");
              return ListTile(
                leading: Image.network(snapshot.data[index].toString(),fit: BoxFit.cover,width: 100,height: 50,),

              );
            });
          }
      }),
```

Comment: O que está sendo informado são os tipos de dados que são incompatíveis. Só pelo trecho de código que postou não consegui reproduzir o erro. Seria melhor ter o exemplo completo pra conseguir abrir no VSCode sem problemas de importação.

Comment: Uma dica que posso passar é para que utilize as mensagens do seu editor para ver o tipo de retorno da sua função e se ela é compatível com o que está sendo esperado na chamada que fez utilizando-a.

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui testar também, mas talvez se vc colocar um `await` nessa linha:

```dart
   return await test;
```

provavelmente vai funcionar